# How to make the first letter of specific array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a simple regex that trims urls to their root domain.

**Problem:** How to make the first letter of a specific array in PHP ? The array output is an associative array. The line echo $matches[0] is the output that I need to convert the first letter to capitalize.

```
 <?php
 $pattern = '/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
 $url = 'http://www.test.com.uk';
 //echo $url;
 if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches) === 1) {
 echo $matches[0];
 }
 ?>
```

The **code works okay** except that the associative array must have a **capitalize letter**
The output of the code above looks like this: test.com.uk

**Output:** But the output I am looking for is this: Test.com.uk

Please help me.

Comment: use `ucfirst('test.com.uk');`

Comment: Instead of fiddling around with regexes, why don't you use the `parse_url` function?

Comment: @lxg: it's a good idea, but it doesn't work if the scheme is not present (or at least a double slash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) on your match:

```
echo ucfirst($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Hello John.. I appreciate your answer is correct. Thank you!

Comment: @Redshot [don't forget to accept the answer which helped you the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @Avinash.. Yes, I am waiting for the interval to finish.

Comment: i posted the above link because you're a new user to SO. Welcome to StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ucfirst](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) function:

```
echo ucfirst($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `ucfirst` php function

```
echo ucfirst($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be more appropriate instead of regex:

```
echo ucfirst(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
```